# Simple URL Yii2

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, yii2

Project Yii2 Basic [v2.0.12]:

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*)$ /web/fonts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /web/images/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule (.*)$ /web/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

and

```
web/.htaccess

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

config\web.php

```
'baseUrl' => '',
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        // ...
    ],
],
```

Not Working.. Why?! I not understand why it not working.. and tell me please what is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to set `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess` file, if your folder is in sub-directory.

Comment: no, test/web, I use OpenServer

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenServer but isn't there option to point virtual host to `web` folder right from the beginning? You can avoid all the redirects in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set your base url in config/web.php

```
use \yii\web\Request;

$baseUrl = str_replace('/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());
$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
'components' => [
'request' => [
            //DEFINE FOR REST API. RESPONSE SHOULD BE JSON FORMAT
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ],
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'basic',
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
        ],
],
```